# reaching the btn event outside the revealing patterned applied class

Tags: javascript, jquery, revealing-module-pattern

I have an revealing patterned applied class.How can I reach `btnMenu` event outside of the `model`
thanks.

```
MyModel= (function () {     
    var btnClickEvents = function () {     
        var btnMenu = $('.btnMenu').on('click', function () {
            var date=  $(this).attr("data-rezerve-date");
            var statu= $(this).attr("data-rezerve-statu");
            alert("click"+date+'---'+statu);
        });    
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize,
        asignValues: asignValues,
        getRezervationDateAndStatus: btnClickEvents.btnMenu//how can I reach this function outside of model    
    };
})();
```

**update**
I change my code as u show.and add one return function

```
MyModel = (function () {
    var dt = "";
    var statu = "";
    var rvalue = {};
    var btnClickEvents = function () {
        $('.btnMenu').on('click', onBtnMenuClick);
    };

    function onBtnMenuClick(e) {
         dt = $(this).attr("data-rezerve-date");
         statu = $(this).attr("data-rezerve-statu");
         rvalue.date = dt;
         rvalue.statu = statu;
         console.log(dt);
    }
    var getRezervationDateAndStatus = function () {

        return rvalue;
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize,
        asignValues: asignValues,

        getRezervationDateAndStatus: getRezervationDateAndStatus
    };
})();
```

and after include my module to my web page calling is like this,

```
MyModel.asignValues(rezervasyonTable,data);
    MyModel.initialize();
    var result = MyModel.getRezervationDateAndStatus();
    console.log(result.date);
```

bu console log empty.

Comment: Did you call btnClickEvents() function in initialize(), and also the rvalue object will have values only after the button class="btnMenu" will be clicked. If you want to fire the onClick event of an element using jQuery add this line of code $('#myButtonnId').trigger('click');  before var result = MyModel.getRezervationDateAndStatus();    And add id="myButtonnId" to the HTML of the button you want.

Comment: I call btnClickEvents() function in initialize().and getting the result after clciked button

Comment: I have more then button generated dynamically so not possiable to get the id

Comment: I guess there is no way to do that,by the way,thank you your effords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say it is a " revealing" pattern. You could see what you expose. To be able to use this function outside of the module change your code like this:

```
MyModel = (function () {
    var btnClickEvents = function () {
        $('.btnMenu').on('click', onBtnMenuClick);
    };

    function onBtnMenuClick(e) {
        var date = $(this).attr("data-rezerve-date");
        var statu = $(this).attr("data-rezerve-statu");
        alert("click" + date + '---' + statu);
    }

    return {
        initialize: initialize,
        asignValues: asignValues,
        getRezervationDateAndStatus: onBtnMenuClick
    };
})();
```

Comment: thank your answer.is it possiable inside  onBtnMenuClick   return { date: date, status: status }; object.I tried it but nothing happened.here is the how I do that:  var result = MyModel.getRezervationDateAndStatus();
        alert(result);

Comment: onBtnMenuClick is an event handler function and it is supposed to be called only when onClick event happens. If you want to return some data when event fires it is necessary to store the data in variable inside a module and get it when you need it, or call another function with this data as parameter to do the job.

Comment: this not work ,Imean store data in variable inside in module,

Comment: Ok, if so you should explain what exactly you want to do?